# No import module find

Tags: python, python-2.7

1. I tried to  **import a module in script** saved on Desktop using cmd in Windows but I get the error:

> "No Module name request"

2. I have installed the module using `pip` and when i import the module from the python interpreter i have no errors.
3. I also [changed the environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1VBi.jpg) variable, should I put the path where the libraries are stored on the script?

Comment: what module? exactly what code did you use?

Comment: How are you executing your python script? Do you have a shebang at the top; or are you manually calling python?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to import the `requests` library but did `import request` instead (i.e., left of the last `s`? That is what it looks like from your error message, but I don't know if it is from a typo in the message or a typo in the code.

Comment: I manually execute the code on the cmd   C:\users\ desktop\filename.py. elethan requests is included in the script

Comment: Jacob i don't have any shebang